# Jquery json multiple data returns undefined

Tags: php, jquery, json, post

I have got licz.php

```
<?php 
echo json_encode(array("a"=>"John","b"=>"2pm")); 
?>
```

and script in index.php

```
<script>
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "licz.php",
          datatype: "json",
          success: function(data) {
                  var json_x = data[0];
                  alert(json_x.a);
                  alert(json_x.b);       
            }

        });
</script>
```

But I got alert "undefined" What's wrong?

Comment: print the `data` variable without the `[0]` in the console.log and look what it looks like.

Comment: Start by inspecting `data`. What's in it?

Comment: Is that the entire code in licz.php, or is there other output (eg another echo json...)? If thats the only output, see the answer by Matei

Comment: console.log returns "undefinied"

Comment: yes, its entire code in licz.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` is an object and you can access directly the `a` and `b` keys. If not, then you have to parse the JSON data using `JSON.parse()` method.

```
success: function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(data.a);
    alert(data.b);       
}
```

Comment: It also returns "undefinied"

Comment: I think you'll need to parse it with `data = JSON.parse(data)` before being able to use `data.a` and you can always `console.debug(data)` and see what's returning from the php is exactly what you want

Comment: Thank you @MoshMage I've updated the code with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

just try this :

licz.php :

```
<?php 
    myArray = array();
    myArray[0]["a"] = "John";
    myArray[0]["b"] = "2pm";
    echo json_encode(myArray); 

?>
```

and .js :

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "licz.php",
        success: function(data) {
            var myTable = JSON.parse(data);
            for(var i =0;i<myTable.length;i++){
                alert(myTable[i].a);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```